# Antd Menu not loading in on the first load of a Next.js app

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, antd

I am running a Next.js app and for the NavBar I'm using antd's Menu component.
The problem is, on the first load of the page (on both on a local host and server hosted website) the Menu items don't load. Instead a "..." is displayed.
Any idea on what might be causing this?

Here's the code:

```html
<Menu className={styles.menuContainer} mode='horizontal'>
  <Menu.Item key='setting:1'>
    <NextLink href='/investors'>
      <a style={{ color: 'var(--color-blue-9)' }}>Investors</a>
    </NextLink>
  </Menu.Item>
  <SubMenu key='SubMenu' title='Resources'>
    <Menu.Item key='setting:2'>
      <Link href='/faq'>Frequently Asked Questions</Link>
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key='setting:3'>
      <Link href='/blog'>Blog</Link>
    </Menu.Item>
  </SubMenu>
</Menu>
```

First Load

[image: First Load]

Refreshes after the first load

[image: Refreshes after first load]

Comment: Can you share a link to server hosted site?

Comment: Can you show us the CSS you're using for the `Menu`?